# PyTorch AutoEncoder : mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x512 and 12x64)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I am trying to pass the output features of a CNN through an AutoEncoder. I used a hooklayer to extract the features of the CNN and converted them into a tensor.

`extracted_features = torch.tensor(rn_output)`

The size of the data after the conversion from tuple to tensor is `torch.Size([1014,512])`

The decoder section of the AutoEncoder is throwing the 'cannot be multiplied error' but my belief is the error is due to the setup and shape of the input.

**AutoEncoder**

```
class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=256),  # N, 512 -> N,128 
            nn.ReLU(),  # Activation Function
            nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=64),
            nn.ReLU(),  # Activation Function
            nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=12),
        )
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=12, out_features=64),  # N, 3 -> N,12 
            nn.ReLU(),  # Activation Function
            nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=128),
            nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=256),
            nn.ReLU(),  # Activation Function
            nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=512),
            nn.Tanh()
        )
    
    def forward(self, x):
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(x)
        return decoded
```

**Call to Autoencoder**

```
model = AutoEncoder()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimiser = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3, weight_decay=1e-5)

num_epochs = 10
outputs = []
for epoch in range(num_epochs): 
    for (img) in extracted_features:
        recon = model(img)
        loss = criterion(recon, img)
        
        optimiser.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimiser.step()
        
    print(f'Epoch:{epoch+1}, Loss:{loss.item():.4f}')
    outputs.append((epoch, img, recon))
```

I have tried using a dataloader and passing the data in with a smaller batch size. I have also tried reshaping the images within the forward method but I still continue to get the same error

Comment: Tip: specifying the Python and package(s) versions, as well as posting the complete traceback of the exception may help someone to reproduce the error and understand what your problem is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your `forward` function is incorrectly performing the encoder-decoder step. I think you should change it from this:

```py
encoded = self.encoder(x)
decoded = self.decoder(x)
```

to this:

```py
encoded = self.encoder(x)
decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
```

The decoder generally operates on the encoded input not directly on the input itself, unless you're using a non-standard definition of encoder-decoder I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: Well spotted, silly error from myself many thanks.